# A lovely three days or lovely three days

Tags: articles, adjectives, singular-vs-plural, determiners

I came across a sentence which reads:

> We spent a lovely three weeks in Canada.

Also sentences which read:

> 1. A staggering 100 students attended the fee class.
> 2. We have reached an amazing 1000 members this month.

My question is why to use 'a/an' where there are plural numbers like 'three weeks', '100 students', '1000 members'.

Comment: You could also say, "We spent three lovely weeks in Canada." However you can't say, "We spend lovely three weeks in Canada."  @JavaLatte explained it.

Answer (score 4):

When you use **a** before a number like this, you are effectively referring to however many they are as a group of some sort, rather than the individual members of the group. Because there is only one group, it's singular so you use **a**.

> a lovely [period of] three weeks.
>   a staggering [group of] 100 students.
>   an amazing [group of] 1000 members.

It is necessary to do this when you want to apply an adjective to the group, rather than to individual members of the group:

> an amazing 1000 members. -*adjective applies to group*
>   1000 amazing members - *adjective applies to members*.